# error: cannot find symbol; symbol: variable keyBoard

Tags: java

I have this code and tried to compile it. But it gave me

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> anotherEntry = keyBoard.nextInt();
>
> symbol: variable keyBoard
>
> location: class DemoVariables3

Any clue why?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoVariables3
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     int entry;
     int anotherEntry;
     System.out.print("Enter another integer ");
     anotherEntry = keyBoard.nextInt();
     System.out.print("The other entry is ");
     System.out.println(anotherEntry);
     System.out.println(entry + "plus" +
    anotherEntry + "is" + (entry + anotherEntry));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable named `keyBoard` and assign it to a new `Scanner` object before you try using the variable `keyBoard`:

```
Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
```